# Cannot get ProgressDialog to display in Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, progressdialog

Well I've seen a wide variety of failures while trying to get this to work. I have a thread that is started via an Activity. The thread needs to create/display progress dialogs and dismiss them.

When I tried to directly display the ProgressDialog I got an error that my Looper wasn't prepared. I looked up with a Looper was an implemented it. However, I had to call Looper.loop for the progress dialog to show up. After it showed up the application froze on that point never to continue past the Looper.loop call.

I couldn't get it to work so looked for a whole new way using a HandlerThread and a Handler. I create a HandlerThread and start it. I get the looper from the thread and create a Handler with it. My ProgressDialog or Toasts won't show up at all.

Is there an easier way to go about doing this?

Comment: Can you post your code here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can have an

```
private Handler stopProgressHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {         
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }
};
private Handler startProgressHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {         
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }
};
```

so that when u start the thread start the `progressbar` and after thread is completed u can stop the `progressbar`.

```
 public void closeProgressbar(){
    //bluetoothconnector.onDestroy();
    stopProgressHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
 }
public void openProgressbar(){
    //bluetoothconnector.onDestroy();
    startProgressHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
 }
```

This will help to call the `progressbar` to start and stop.. This will be one of the solution..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about ProgressDialog, but all UI related stuff in Android, as far as I know, required to be updated in UI Thread. There's actually an easy helper class for implementing async task: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Alternatively, you can create a Handler (which would be on UI Thread) and create the dialog using that:

```
Handler uiHandler;
//Activity onCreate
onCreate(...){
    uiHandler = new Handler();
}

// Somewhere in your other thread, 
uiHandler.postRunnable(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
       // Create or update dialog
       ...
    }
});
```

Comment: An alternative is to use runOnUiThread() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Answer (score 0):

The last answer is wrong....

it should be:

setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE | Boolean.FALSE);